# How to add a repeating pattern to vector with different length in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

**Question**

Suppose I have two vectors of arbitrary length. Lets call one `pattern` and the other `series`. Now I want to add my repeated `pattern` to my `series` in an automatic way.

Typically one can assume that `pattern` is shorter than `series`, but it would be nice if the alternate way also worked. In this case just the first few values of `pattern` should be used.

**Example**

```
pattern = 1:3;
series = 1:10;
```

Should give

```
 2     4     6     5     7     9     8    10    12    11
```

**What have I found so far?**

I have searched around but did not find an elegant way to achieve what I want.

- The easiest solution I found uses `padarray`, however I do not have this available
- My own solution,that I don't consider to be elegant, is using `repmat` to repeat the pattern a sufficient amount of times and then cutting of the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use indexing instead of repmat:

```
result = series + pattern([mod(0:(numel(series) - 1), numel(pattern)) + 1]);
```

Comment: Definately meets the criteria, I am curious to see whether anyone can provide alternatives.