# Creating a MATLAB vector with an overlapping pattern

Tags: matlab, design-patterns, vector

I have an array containing a pattern:

```
p = [1, 2, 2, 1];
```

I want to replicate the pattern but need to add the first and last elements.  I'd prefer to find a better way than looping, if possible.

Meaning:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1]
         [1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

I found something that does almost exactly what I need here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545970/2434277

But I can't find a way to make the overlap-addition happen.  That is, it does this:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Quick edit: I'll need to replicate several times, but I don't know the number in advance.

Comment: Just looping through a vector of the required size and putting the appropriate number in depending on index.  I used mod on the index to figure out which number to put it.  It actually works OK; I'm just wondering if there is a nicer, non-brute-force way of doing it.

Comment: Did you want to write [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1] instead of [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1] ?

Comment: @user2987828: No - I need the last element of the previous replica and the first element of the next replica to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
p = [1, 2, 2, 1];

n = length(p);
p(end + n - 1) = 0; %//pad with 0s
p(n:end) = p(n:end) + p(1:n)
```

Or you could do it in one line if you want:

```
[p, zeros(1, length(p)-1] + [zeros(1, length(p)-1, p]
```

But if you want a general solution for `m` repetitions then I suggest you use `conv` (as answered by user2987828) like this:

```
k = []; %// Leave off this line if you are certain that k won't exist yet
n = length(p);
k(1:n-1:(n-1)*m+1)=1; 
conv(k,p);
```

Comment: Fantastic and accepted.  A hell of a lot nicer than my loop approach.  It'd be fun to see more ideas, if any.  @Dan, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Is it conv that you are looking for ?

```
> conv([1 0 0 0 1],[1 2 2 1])
 1     2     2     1     1     2     2     1

> conv([1 0 0 1],[1 2 2 1])
 1     2     2     2     2     2     1
```

The first argument of conv may also be a sparse matrix:

```
full(sparse(1,[1 5 18],1))
  1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
conv(full(sparse(1,[1 5 18],1)),[1 2 2 1])
  1     2     2     1     1     2     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     2     1
```

Comment: Very cool.  I knew it resembled an operation I had seen before!  Thanks!

Comment: This is nice because you can replicate it many times in one shot: `conv([1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1],[1 2 2 1])` or in general (i.e. replicate `n` times: `k(1:length(p)-1:(length(p)-1)*n+1)=1; conv(k,p);`